# doing a task forever when my app opens - how to?

Tags: android, service, background, intentservice, android-jobscheduler

its more than 3 weeks try all types of background services, (intentservice... etc) it work but problem it stop after android going to sleep mode, so to avoid i try to add use (runnble, thread, and also while loop), but same issue, when mob going in sleep mode all task work stop even using wakeup method/permissions.

MainActivity (public void) [which i use to do task]

```
 public void do_my_task_every_25sec(){

 // working for 1000 as total number.
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {

    System.out.println("Starting Again Number :"+i);

    Updating_Last_one = Long.parseLong(Updated.getText().toString());
     .....

        SystemClock.sleep(25000); // sleep 25 sec to start again.
        }


  }
```

---

for now no services background to provide, it many services i just try before.

i will be glade for your help i still new in android development, just wanna make sure task work even in sleep mode, also if i close app, service will stop. i Believe in Stackoverflow devs power, Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You should try a Foreground Service. 
this will require that you have a notification constantly on the notification bar of the user, but it will allow your process to keep running.

just make sure you don't drain his battery.

here is an example

```
public class ForegroundService extends Service {
public static final String CHANNEL_ID = "ForegroundServiceChannel";

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    String input = intent.getStringExtra("inputExtra");
    createNotificationChannel();
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
            0, notificationIntent, 0);

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle("Foreground Service")
            .setContentText(input)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build();

    startForeground(1, notification);

    //do heavy work on a background thread


    //stopSelf();

    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

}

private void createNotificationChannel() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel serviceChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                CHANNEL_ID,
                "Foreground Service Channel",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
        );

        NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel);
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry for my delay, i was outside home, i gonna try it now, :)

Comment: how to call back `public void do_my_task_every_25sec()` from MainActivity to make it work for forever.